# "stop: 0x0000007B (0xBACC3528,0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)" error after launching Eclipse

Tags: windows, hard-drive, virus

I am not even sure this is the place to ask such a question but I am desperate right now. I just got blue screen error message on Windows after launching Eclipse. The error code is

> stop: 0x0000007B (0xBACC3528,0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)

It seems that I cant open windows from this point on. I checked the internet and found out that the message is about driver configurations or boot-sector viruses. Some of the sites I used:

http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/windows-nt-2000-xp/threads/121989/stop-0x0000007b-0xbacc35280xc0000034-0x00000000-0x00000000

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=as0-g0bl85A

Is it possible to fix it, or do you think that it is relevant with the Eclipse? Actually I can easily reinstall the windows but there were some valuable piece of code on that computer. If you think that this is beyond repair, can I save them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you boot into [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-hk/windows-vista/start-your-computer-in-safe-mode)? If you can, you can copy all your data to safety there. If not, you could use a bootable linux live Cd (prety much any distro will do) to easily copy off important data from your hardrive if you have to reinstall Windows.

I have no idea if Eclipse could cause this. I'd say it is possible but improbable. (That, however, really doesn't help you to fix it...) Have you installed any drivers or software with drivers lately? Faulty drivers are probably the most common reason for bluescreens. AFAIK Eclipse doesn't install any drivers (I could be wrong, but I don't expect IDEs to install any drivers). If you can boot to safe mode, try uninstalling any such drivers and see if that helps.

If it's not a faulty driver, some system file might be corrupted. You could try fixing it by running "sfc /scannow" (google it for more help) from safe mode command prompt or recovery console on installation disk.

If that doesn't help and reinstalling windows doesn't feel too painful and you can backup your data, it could be the next fastest solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used Ubuntu to access my files. I am formatting my hard disc right now.